# amgularjs+Jquery : foreach loop doesnot exit properly

Tags: jquery, .net, angularjs

**Update** : I have updated the Braces

i have validation method before saving .there ,a foreach loop execute which should return bool flag if one condition meet and should exit

```
$.each($scope.vacationSummaries, function (i, v) 
  {
    if (Number($scope.vacationRequest.VacationType.Id) == Number(v.VacationType.Id))
       {
        if (v.Remaining > 0)
        return true; //for returning a true flag for save
       }
   return false; // for exiting for each loop
  });
```

..but it returning false flag for save and not exiting from for each

How can i do it Right ??

Answer (score 1):

:edit after you corrected your code

So your issue is that you want to return true, if the conditions of both if statements match. This doesn't work within a $.each loop because the loop simply runs the function as a callback for each item in your collection.

It is basically the same as if you would have

```
 for(var key in $scope.vacationSummaries){
     var v = $scope.vacationSummaries[key];
     ...
 }
```

Within a for each loop you cannot use return.

Instead, you'll have to do something with the object instance `v` for example. If you want to flag something, define a variable before starting the loop and assign true or false. Simply flag an object within the loop. Or if you want to do something with the object, call another function...

Some examples:

```
var flag=false;
$.each($scope.vacationSummaries, function (i, v) 
{
    if (Number($scope.vacationRequest.VacationType.Id) == Number(v.VacationType.Id))
    {
        if (v.Remaining > 0) {
            flag = true; //assigning flag which can be used after the loop?
            save(v); // call a method which does something with v?
        }
    }
    return false; // for exiting for each loop
});
```

Honestly I don't exactly know what you want to achieve because I can only see this small part of your code ;) 
Simply think of the $.each method as if it would a normal for each loop in C# or JavaScript and implement your logic accordingly

Comment: No , it is not working either ,returning false working fine , but return true not giving true flag...

Comment: return within an each loop does not work as if you would return something from a function. return false will break the loop, return anything else than false, simply continues the loop, which makes it somewhat obsolete

Comment: yes , i agreed , but it there any around ? to get a true flag within foreach loop ??? .... like there is also simple validation applied like     if ($scope.vacationRequest.VacationType == null)             return false; ...it simply sending false flag for save , can we do it in foreach loop ??

Comment: Possibly you'd prefer a `while` loop?  Or to keep with the `each` construct you could pass in a `valid` variable as a parameter, use it in place of the returns (and possibly keep the return true if you want to drop out of the loop upon finding a valid value) and test `valid` upon completion of the loop.

Comment: see updated answer. Think of a normal for each loop where you cannot use the return statement and implement your logic accordingly.

Comment: I only want to achieve that when flag is true , the save button should be enable for "Save" operation.. nyway thanks for answer

Comment: Ok but that's extremly easy to do now right? If you have any other issues, please create a new question and accept one of the answers...

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.vacations = function() {
  var check = false;

  angular.forEach($scope.vacationSummaries,function(v,i) {
    if (Number($scope.vacationRequest.VacationType.Id) == Number(v.VacationType.Id)) {
          if (v.Remaining > 0) {
            check = true; //for returning a true flag for save
          }
    } else {
      check = false; // for exiting for each loop
    }
  });

  return check;

}
```